# Converting a string into array of integers

Tags: c#-4.0

The following is a piece of code I have written

```
string arrayToConvert = "$78 89 12 78 89 12%";
string s2 = s1.Substring(1, s1.Length - (2));
```

There are 2 objectives to be achieved

1. Removing the first and last character
2. Transferring the string data into array of integers

I am able to remove the first and last character in a string and store it into a new one, no problem. The trouble is when I try to put the data into integer array. I tried using the following syntax to achieve the desired goal.

```
int[] ia = s1.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

and

```
int n;
int[] ia = s1.Split(' ').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out n) ? n : 0).ToArray();
```

The output obtained is "4455667788110121" which clearly are not the numbers in the input string. If this question is a duplicate, kindly point me in the right direction. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you output the int[]?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  The first snippet works `"78 89 12 78 89 12".Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()` returns an array with 6 elements whose values are 78, 89, etc

Comment: Are you using the wrong strings perhaps? The original string is `arrayToConvert` yet you trim a different string, s1. Finally, you try to split that s1 string, not the trimmed one

Comment: Your string is `arrayToConvert` but you try to substring and split a string `s1`. Is this defined somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Yes, it was a synctactical error, thanks for pointing it out. The snippet does  work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are using the wrong strings. Your original string is `arrayToConvert yet you try to clean up some other string, s1. Finally you try to split s1, not the cleaned up s2.

The following line returns an array with the expected values:

```
var ints= "$78 89 12 78 89 12%"
              .Trim(new[]{'$','%'})
              .Split(' ')
              .Select(int.Parse)
              .ToArray();
```

I used `Trim` rather than `Substring` simply to put everything in a single statement.

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution I have come across yet. I appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: Sir, conversely if I had to eliminate all special characters, alphabets and keep only the numbers is the string. For example "$67%!" or "$127a%". I am obtaining data from serial port and in certain cases there are alphabets/ special chars between $ and % or may be a number after %

Comment: @amatuer_programmer if you have another question, post it as a new question, not as a comment

Comment: Okay, fine, noted.